# Table variables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, plsql

I am new to the database concepts. I currently have SQL Server code which i am trying to convert to Oracle.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_CSVToTable] ( @StringInput VARCHAR(8000) )
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ( [String] VARCHAR(20) )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @String    VARCHAR(20)

    WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @String      = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                                ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput) - 1, 
        -1),
                                LEN(@StringInput)))
        SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                     ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput), 
        0),
                                     LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

    INSERT INTO @OutputTable ( [String] )
        VALUES ( @String )
    END

    RETURN
END
```

I am unable to find any concept of table variable in oracle.

Can anybody help me to know how to replace the table variable in oracle.

Posting my conversion to oracle below *based on my understanding from the questions already asked on SO:*

```
CREATE TYPE Output AS OBJECT (str VARCHAR2 (20));

CREATE TYPE OutputTable AS TABLE OF Output;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ufn_CSVToTable (p_StringInput VARCHAR2)
    RETURN OutputTable
AS
    v_String        VARCHAR2 (20);
    v_StringInput   VARCHAR2 (8000);
BEGIN
    WHILE LENGTH (RTRIM (p_StringInput)) > 0
    LOOP
        v_String :=
            SUBSTR (
                p_StringInput,
                1,
                NVL (NULLIF (INSTR (p_StringInput, ',') - 1, -1),
                     LENGTH (RTRIM (p_StringInput))));
        v_StringInput :=
            SUBSTR (
                p_StringInput,
                  NVL (NULLIF (INSTR (p_StringInput, ','), 0),
                       LENGTH (RTRIM (p_StringInput)))
                + 1,
                LENGTH (RTRIM (p_StringInput)));

        INSERT INTO Output (str)
             VALUES (v_String);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
END;
```

But i am still getting the below errors:

> 1.[Error] ORA-04044 (25: 21): PL/SQL: ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here.
>
> 2.[Error] PLS-00503 (29: 5): PLS-00503: RETURN statement required for this return from function

**NOTE**:I had asked this question before but it was closed so asking it again with the converted code in oracle based on my understanding from content read on SO.

Comment: Instead of asking directly how to convert from one code to another, tell us about your sample data and final expected result. There may be much better ways in Oracle to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return anything:

```
RETURN;
```

Should be something like;

```
RETURN myTableOfMyTypeVariableWhichIDidDeclareBetweenAsAndBegin;
```

Here some anonymous block to explain how to return something (return is out-commented becaus it only works in functions):

```
declare
    TYPE myTableType IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (20); -- define type
    v_myTable myTableType; -- define variable of your type
begin
    v_myTable := myTableType(); 

    v_myTable.extend;
    v_myTable(1) := 'Test1';

    v_myTable.extend;
    v_myTable(2) := 'Test2';

    dbms_output.put_line('v_myTable(1): ' || v_myTable(1));
    dbms_output.put_line('v_myTable(2): ' || v_myTable(2)); 

    --return v_MyTable; -- Return the object you created / Works only within a function
end;
```

Comment: i want to return the table which i am declaring above the function here,so dont konw how to do that

Comment: I added a full example for a Table-Of-Something-Type

Comment: @vikky If The answer helps you can Accept IT ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can return `sys_refcursor`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ufn_CSVToTable (p_StringInput VARCHAR2)
    return sys_refcursor 
is
   rf_cur   sys_refcursor;
   v_String        VARCHAR2 (20);
   v_StringInput   VARCHAR2 (8000);
BEGIN
    WHILE LENGTH (RTRIM (p_StringInput)) > 0
    LOOP
        v_String :=
            SUBSTR (
                p_StringInput,
                1,
                NVL (NULLIF (INSTR (p_StringInput, ',') - 1, -1),
                     LENGTH (RTRIM (p_StringInput))));
        v_StringInput :=
            SUBSTR (
                p_StringInput,
                  NVL (NULLIF (INSTR (p_StringInput, ','), 0),
                       LENGTH (RTRIM (p_StringInput)))
                + 1,
                LENGTH (RTRIM (p_StringInput)));

        INSERT INTO Output (str)
             VALUES (v_String);
    END LOOP;
     open rf_cur for
      select *
        from Output;
   return rf_cur;
END;
```